# Crop image and then stretch to fill available space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to crop an image from an url and then stretch the cropped image to the available space.

```
<div style="width:300px; height:400px;">
  <img style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb95aa803f8c6d536afc87bf8d641ed4?s=128&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" />
</div>
```

This will stretch the image appropriately, but I do not know how to crop it. I have tried to use `clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);` but the image will stretch to the available space first and then apply the clip, so it doesn't work for me.

Edit - jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjMp6/

For example, I want to try and just crop the head and then stretch the head

Comment: can you make a fiddle from it?

Comment: @SvenBieder - What does fiddle mean?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is a convenient way to share and test html/js/css code

Comment: The solution I see would be fetch the image and then draw it in a canvas with drawImage

Comment: Why would one need a jsfiddle from 3 lines of code? I think it's totally unnecessary here.

Comment: bevause your 3 lines of code are the most unimportant part of your problem. where is the css that does your work?

Comment: @SvenBieder it's in the style-attributes ;)

Comment: in your css is only the size and nothing else. I know that I only need to add the clip style to it, but it is important to see how exactly you have implemented it, because very often it happens that people have stuff in the wrong order for the desired result.

Comment: @SvenBieder - I don't have an external css file. I provided all the css inline. I only know the original image size, but I wont know the final size.

Comment: this is a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808889/is-there-a-way-to-use-javascript-to-crop-resize-an-image-before-displaying-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off of Yoshi's idea without the second div

```
div
{
    width:300px; 
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
img
{
    width:300%; 
    height:300%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-50%;
}
```

Added the border just to see the containing div.  This way you will not need to know the dims of the container but for cropping an image you will have to play with the number with any solution unless all of the images have the same relative composition ie headshots or something similar.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjMp6/) for your viewing pleasure.

Also as the container grows/shrinks your image will retain the same crop and position.

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle to illustrate the canvas solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/mDy24/

Here's the html :

```
   <div id=theimg style="width:300px; height:400px;">
          <canvas id=thecanvas style="width:100%;height:100%;">
   </div>​
```

And the js :

```
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb95aa803f8c6d536afc87bf8d641ed4?s=128&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG";
   img.onload = function() {
          var can = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
          var con = can.getContext("2d");
          console.log(con);
          con.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, can.width, can.height);
   }​
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do like the approach and I might use it in the future, but I am going to stick with a pure css solution

Comment: As long as your transformation is feasible in css, you should use css, I agree. I was posting this mainly to illustrate this more powerful possibility as I know too many people ignore the efficiency of canvas.